# Is it possible to change the status of filefield in admin - DJANGO

Tags: django, django-admin, filefield

I'm new with django and I was wondering if it is possible to change the status **Currently**(see the pic) of a filefield to other things like maybe: all, list...
Because **currently** only return the last uploaded item. I have uploaded 5 file(File1, FIle2, .., File5) on a specific field, base on user ID, but it only return file5.
I want to display all uploaded files and be able to get it via template.

[See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YmPf.png)

I am able to see the complete list after the insertion in the db, via command prompt but only the last uploaded file is display in django admin.

My models.py :

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
    codePerm = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    files = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
```

admin.py :

```
@admin.register(Student)
class userdat(ImportExportModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('name', 'codePerm', 'files')            
        pass
```

My project consists in processing data from an excel file.
There are more than 10 000 elements in the excel file.

I can import the excel file into the sqlite DB and i can browse the data.
However each student has files (5 files) associated with them that are saved locally in a folder that I need to add to the DB.
I am looking for a way to import all 5 files per student in one go to save time instead of importing the files one by one for each student since I have over 10,000 students it would take me longer.

Is there a way to import the files grouped by student or what would be the best way to process the data? Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Please show your models and admin.py

Comment: @IvanBeliakov i added models and admin.py

Comment: `models.FileField` by default does not allow to upload multiple images. So most likely when you try to upload several files, only the last one gets uploaded. What you need is a separate model for images with `ForeignKey` to your `Student` model. If you have any special code for FileField (perhaps in `ImportExportModelAdmin`?), please show it. If you need help with structuring a separate model for files, let me know and I will write an answer

Comment: Sorry, replace "images" with "files" :)

Comment: @IvanBeliakov Thanks! i'm going to try first and let you know. Also i have added more informations about what i trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `models.FileField` in your `Student` model you can add only one file for each student. Every new upload replaces the old file. That is why in the admin you only see the file that is currently in the database. If you want to add more than one file for each student, you need to use ForeignKey and Inline. Here is an example (you need to adjust it to work with your `ImportExportModelAdmin` class):

**models.py**

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
    codePerm = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

class StudentFiles(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey('Student',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='files'
    )
    file = models.FileField()
```

**admin.py**

```
from .models import Student, StudentFiles

class StudentFilesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = StudentFiles

@admin.register(Student)
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):           
        inlines = [StudentFilesInline,]
```

Now if you want to upload multiple files at once, you are going to need a custom form field for this. I find [this tutorial](https://xn--w5d.cc/2019/09/18/minimalistic-multiupload-in-django-admin.html) helpful. For example, you can create `forms.py` in your app and add this code:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Student, StudentFiles

class StudentAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        # Display all default fields without change
        fields = '__all__'
    
    # Create a new field with 'multiple' attribute
    files = forms.FileField(
        widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        label='Upload multiple files at once',
        required=False,
    )

    def save_files(self, student):
        # Save each file in the StudentFiles model
        for upload in self.files.getlist('files'):
            file = StudentFiles(student=student, file=upload)
            file.save()
```

And then adjust the `admin.py` accordingly:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Student, StudentFiles
from .forms import StudentAdminForm

class StudentFilesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = StudentFiles

@admin.register(Student)
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):         
    inlines = [StudentFilesInline,]
    form = StudentAdminForm

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        super().save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
        form.save_files(form.instance)
```

With all of this you will be able to upload many files at once and later replace/delete any of them.

**EDIT:** There is a simpler way explained in [this Quora post](https://qr.ae/pr2APb). You can get rid of the `save_files()` and `save_related()`. Use `save_model()` instead:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Student

class StudentAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        # Display all default fields without change
        fields = '__all__'

    # Create a new field with 'multiple' attribute
    files = forms.FileField(
        widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        label='Upload multiple files at once',
        required=False,
    )
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Student, StudentFiles
from .forms import StudentAdminForm

class StudentFilesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = StudentFiles

@admin.register(Student)
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):         
    inlines = [StudentFilesInline,]
    form = StudentAdminForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change): 
        obj.save() 
 
        for file in request.FILES.getlist('files'): 
            obj.files.create(file=file)
```

Comment: Thank you very muchhh , this is exactly what I was looking for. And it works like a charm. Thank you again for your preciouse help and your time.

Comment: Glad to be of help. By the way, notice that in the database you only save the path to your files, not the actual files. So if all of your files are saved in separate folders with a pattern, you don't have to upload them manually in admin.

Comment: For example, if your structure is something like `files_folder/student1/file1, file2, file3...` Then you can simply copy and paste everything to the new location and write a script to insert urls into the database

Comment: Thank you for the added information and details about the file links. Exactly my files have this structure files_folder/student1/file1, file2, file3... 
so would the script be a way to import the files into the database faster depending on the user? I.e. import the files in one go for the 10 000 students?

Comment: If you know for sure that student id's are the same, then yes, you can simply copy all the files to the new place and write a script to import all data in one go

Answer (score 1):

You would need to override the ClearableFileInput using formfield_overrides.

Something like the following

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms import ClearableFileInput

class MyModel(admin.MyModel):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.FileField {'widget':ClearableFileInput(template_name='template.html')},
    }
```

You will have to create a new template change that there, [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/clearable_file_input.html) is how it is implemented in django source.